# Do vim or gVim commands exist to copy text between parentheses?

Tags: vim

In the following code snippet, if I go to the first open parenthesis `(` of the line beginning with `(spit`

```
(defn missing-accts 
    "Prints accounts found in one report but not the other."

    [report-header mapped-data out-file]
    (spit out-file (str "\n\n    " 
          (count mapped-data) 
          "   " report-header 
          "\n\n") :append true)
          .
          .
          .
```

vim highlights the first `(` and closing `)` parentheses.

Is there and, if there is, what is the vim command that would yank the entire spit command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim does have such a command, and fortunately it is very simple.  Just type `y%`.

The reason this works is that `%` is what Vim calls a *movement* command.  It moves from one delimiter to the matching delimiter -- in your case from the opening parenthesis to the closing one.  The `y` command *yanks* a single line into Vim's buffer if invoked as `yy`, but the second `y` is not required.  Instead, one can issue a *movement* like `%`, whereupon Vim will yank the text moved over.  Thus, `y%`.

Answer (score 9):

The sequence

```
va(
```

will highlight from the opening to closing brackets inclusively, and a `y` will then yank that. Note unlike the `%` command, you don't have to be positioned on the bracket - you just need to be inside the clause.

Note that

```
vi(
```

would highlight everything *inside* the brackets, but not the brackets.

You can do this for braces too (`{` instead of `(`) and XML tags (`t` - presumably for *tag*)

Comment: Or simpler, `ya(`, without engaging visual mode. Change to `yi(` if you just want the content without the outer parentheses. Also, works from anywhere inside the parens; you don't need to bring the cursor exactly to a parenthesis.

Comment: @Amadan - thanks for that. Wasn't aware you could do that too

Answer (score 2):

use % with y. press "y" once then "%" ,your cursor should be on "(" when you type the command.